# Are operations on floats supported with bc?

Tags: bc, floating-point

It looks like bc doesn't support float operations. When I do `echo 1/8 | bc` it gets me a zero. I checked the manual page `bc (1)`, but it doesn't even mention `float`, so I wonder if it's supported?

Comment: This [question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66609/round-truncate-digit-in-string-in-zsh-or-with-external-tool) and in particular the accepted [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/66755/13136) might be interesting to you.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

`bc` doesn't do floating point but it does do fixed precision decimal numbers.  The `-l` flag Hauke mentions loads a math library for eg. trig functions but it also means

> [...] the default **scale** is 20

`scale` is one of a number of "special variables" mentioned in the man page.  You can set it:

```
scale=4
```

Anytime you want (whether `-l` was used or not).  It refers to *the number of significant digits used in a decimal*. In other words, subsequent solutions will be rounded **down** to that number of digits after the decimal scale (== fixed precision).

The default scale sans `-l` is 0, meaning rounded (down) to whole numbers.

Comment: Here's an example of how to use scale: `echo "scale=4;22/7" | bc` - Result: 3.1428, a number marginally better than pi.

Answer (score 37):

man page says:

> If  bc  is invoked with the -l option, a math library is preloaded [...]

The comprehensibility of that could be improved, indeed...

Comment: Report it upstream as a bug...

Answer (score 1):

1. Numbers in `bc` have a *scale*. The scale of a number should not be confused with the scale factor. The same world `scale` is used as a function to query the scale of a number or as a parameter to set the scale factor.

   ```bash
   echo "scale=scale(1.1);11/10" | bc will return 1.1
   ```
2. The scale factor (value of the `scale` variable/register) determines how many digits are kept to the right of the decimal point when doing operations. If `s` is the current scale factor, `sa` is the scale of the first operand `a`, `sb` is the scale of the second operand `b`, results are truncated as follows:

   ```
       scale of result
   a+b     max(sa,sb)
   a-b     max(sa,sb)
   a*b     min(sa+sb , max(s,sa,sb))
   a/b     s
   a%b     so that a = b*quotient + remainder; remainder has sign of a
   a^b     min(sa×|b|, max(s,sa)); b must be integer
   sqrt(a) max(s,as)
   ```
3. Originally, `bc` was a preprocessor of `dc`. Now, on many systems, `bc` is a standalone program.

See also [the POSIX specification of `bc`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/bc.html).

Answer (score 0):

Alternative path on MacOS (for short) is using `-e` option with `-l` option.

```
  -e  expr  --expression=expr

      Run "expr" and quit. If multiple expressions or files (see below) are
      given, they are all run before executing from stdin.
```

Example: `bc -e 1/8 -l`

Comment: The `-l` option to load the math functions and to set `scale` to 20 has already been mentioned in other answers. The `-e` option seems to be an extension found only in some implementations of `bc` (not on Busybox systems, for example).

Comment: 1. This path shorter, than path with `echo`; 2. This path for MacOS version of `bc`.